# Getting back object from child activiy in Android

Tags: android

I have a **main_activity** that starts a child `Activity` via `Intent`.

I know about methods `getStringExtra(string)`, or `getBooleanExtra(string)` etc. that we call in `onActivityResult`; But they all `return` a primitive data...
How can I get an object from a user-defined class from the child activity?

Thanks, and this is my first question here! :) kinda too late...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Parcelable` custom object.

like this

```
public class Student implements Parcelable{
```

add to intent like this

```
intent.putExtra("student", obj);
```

Then get That object like

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
Student student = (Student) data.getParcelable("student");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

A simpler, though non optimal solution is [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).

Snippet:

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

Usage:

```
// Sender class
MyParcelable mp = new MyParcelable();
intent.putExtra("KEY_PARCEL", mp);

// Receiver class
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
MyParcelable student = (Myparcelable)data.getParcelable("KEY_PARCEL");
```

[Here's](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html) a working example.

**EDIT**: Here's how to do it with fragments.

```
// Receiver class
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MyFragment newInstance(int index, Bundle data) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        data.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(data);
        return f;
    }

}

// In the fragment
Bundle data = getArguments();
```

Comment: Just to make it clear for noobs like me, it should be getActivity().getIntent().getExtras() if used in fragments!

Comment: @Ashl7 that would work, but not a good design practice. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is this website that makes Parselabel classes out of your custom class....swweeeeeet!
http://www.parcelabler.com/